# web config file not redirecting properly

Tags: php, redirect, web-config

Hi i want my server to redirect from http://www.gorrors.com/title/tt1130884/?ref_=tt_rec_tti

to
www.gorrors.com/imdbredirect.php?imdb=tt1130884

```
<rule name="rule 4l">
    <match url="^imdbredirect.php?imdb=([^/]*)"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/title/tt{R:1}/?ref_=tt_rec_tti"  />
</rule>
```

however this doesn't seem to work, Im sure I am missing something simple?

this is so if a user is on imdb.com they can change the imdb to gorrors.com and they will be fowarded to the same film.

Any help would be great thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule name="rule 1C">
    <match url="^title/(.+)$"  />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/imdbredirect.php?imdb={R:1}"  />
</rule>
```

This fixed my problem I had done the match wrong